# Text input doesn't expand when a chunk of text is pasted

Tags: jquery

I have a text input of initial size, say 2. What I want is that when I type into it, the size should expand simultaneously (which is visible due to the text input's borders), and decrease simultaneously when the user presses backspace/delete to erase characters. I am trying with this code:

```
$("input").live("mouseup mousedown keyup keydown",function() {
x = parseInt($(this).attr('size'));
y = $(this).val().length;
z = x > y ? y : x;
$(this).attr('size',z+2);
});
```

Now this code works just as expected when the user either types one character at a time, or presses a character key and keeps it pressed. Problem arises when I copy a chunk of text from somewhere, focus on the text input, and paste into it either through CTRL-V, or by right-clicking and choosing Paste option. I am testing it with a string of 45 W's. What happens is that the text input expands only a little and stays that way (thus displaying only few W's). Not until I click it that it expands a little more. 2 or 3 subsequent clicks go on expanding it and then it finally expands to the full size. Another quirky thing is that the reverse is not true, when I focus on the input, do a CTRL-A to select the entire text and hit backspace, the size reduces to the original size simultaneously with all the text vanishing. Can anyone explain why is this happening? And how can I auto-expand it simultaneously when a chunk of text is pasted?

Comment: are you sure it's length is of a right size when the function gets called? Maybe it is reading somewhat all text + 1 symbol for ctrl + 1 symbol for V? So my bet would be to check x and y values.

Comment: I didn't quite get what you just said. The check between x and y is to ensure that the input doesn't go on expanding just because the user clicks on it.

Comment: Yeah yeah, but I meant you to look at their values whether they are as you expect.

Comment: Ok, I will add an updater div and see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use 'editable' `div`, like this:

*css*:

```
div.input{
   display:inline-block; 
   border:1px solid; 
   background-color:white;
}
```

​*markup:*

```
<div class="input" contentEditable="true">Type here...</div>​
```

*demo->* [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yb6KC/)

Comment: Wow, that was great! I never knew that **div**'s can be editable as well! However for IE 5 and Opera Mobile, where it is not supported, I will have to use the text input as fallback. So please tell me how to mend that as well!

Comment: I think you can easily forget about IE5, as support for even IE6 is steadily dropping.

Comment: @Cupidvogel IE5, are you serious?

Comment: Ummm, some annoying users still seem to use it! Beside Opera Mobile is used largely....

Comment: And another issue, the input or **compositionupdate** events for tracking changes while typing simultaneously don't work in Firefox prior to version 12 and don't work in Safari at all...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.live("mouseup mousedown keyup keydown")` I would use the `.change()` event which works the same way and would probably catch the CTRL+V changes too.

Comment: No, the **change()** won't work. It fires immediately in case of radio and check buttons, but in case of text input it fires only when the input loses focus, not simultaneously with typing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the events **`propertychange`**(IE) and **`input`**(others) instead.

Comment: Oh man, that was another great solution, except that it doesn't work in Firefox below version 12 or version 9 (for its alias **compositionupdate**)!

Answer (score 0):

Another trick, maybe more cross-compatible, is to trigger a check with a timer.

Comment: Yeah perhaps, but the frequent setting and clearing the timer would take a heavy toll on the overall script execution...

Comment: @Cupidvogel no need to be that frequent (every 0.5 sec would be fine for example). I bet also very code-heavy sites like Facebook use this approach for some things.

Comment: Yeah, but I think it's quite possible without timers. Timers are the last things one should employ while designing, they lock scripts so frequently! For stuff like long polling, that is cursory, of course.

Comment: @Cupidvogel It depends, also on browser compatibility (and that's a concern you mind about, as you stated). For simple tasks like these I would consider the opion viable; that said, I think that `contentEditable` is better and a fairly supported solution, it was only another approach I thought of. :)

Comment: Yeah I know, but even that has issues, as I stated above!